# Is there a method to select elements negatively proportionate to a categorical distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling

I have a categorical distribution which depicts the probability of bad choices. I want to select elements negatively proportionate to that categorical distribution, i.e., if my categorical distribution is [30%, 50%, 20%], then the second element (50%) will have the least probability to be selected, and I hope the last element (20%) will have the greatest probability to be selected. Is there such a method?

Answer (score 1):

If your original probabilities are $p_i, i=1,\ldots d$, use as new probabilities $q_i$ with:
$$q_i = \frac{(1-p_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^d (1-p_i)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is to take the negative value of these probabilities and use the softmax function to transform these values into probabilities.

$$
\sigma(\vec{z})_{i}=\frac{e^{-z_{i}}}{\sum_{j=1}^{K} e^{-z_{j}}}
$$

Comment: This smoothes, so you could never have a probability zero in your result. Depends on what you are looking for...